# Not able to update lambda code on AWS console using terraform

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am creating lambda function using terraform as per the terraform syntax lambda code should be passed as a zip file. In a similar way, I am passing in a resource block and it is getting created also without any issue. But when I am trying to update lambda code using terraform in the next run it is not getting updated. Below block for reference.

```
data "archive_file" "stop_ec2" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_file = "src_dir/stop_ec2.py"
  output_path = "dest_dir/stop_ec2_upload.zip"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "stop_ec2" {
  function_name    = "stopEC2"
  handler          = "stop_ec2.handler"
  runtime          = "python3.6"
  filename         = "dest_dir/stop_ec2_upload.zip"
  role             = "..."
}
```

Need help to resolve this issue.

Comment: You mean, you modify `stop_ec2.py` and re-apply your terraform?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the [source_code_hash](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function#argument-reference) argument, so Terraform will update the lambda function when the lambda code is changed.

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "stop_ec2" {
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("dest_dir/stop_ec2_upload.zip")
```

Comment: I am running into a situation where this isn't working. 1.0.6.